# Change state of member variable in React not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, setstate

I have a class Box2 which I have made an instance of in Box1

Box1 just renders the instance which is has of Box2 however using setState for that instance that I have it doesnt change

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Box2 extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={text:"No"};
    }
    render(){
        return(
        <h1>
            {this.state.text}
        </h1>
        );
    }
}

export default class Box1 extends React.Component{
    Elements=[];
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.Elements[0]=new Box2();
        this.Elements[0].setState({text:"YES"});
    }
    render(){
        return(<div>
        {this.Elements.map((e)=>e.render())};
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change state of your child components. Instead you should use props:

```
class Box2 extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <h1 onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.text}
      </h1>
    );
  }
}

export default class Box1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isBox2Yes: true,
    };

    this.onBoxClick = this.onBoxClick.bind(this);
  }

  onBoxClick() {
    this.setState({ isBox2Yes: !this.state.isBox2Yes });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Box2
          text={this.state.isBox2Yes ? 'YES' : 'NO'}
          onClick={this.onBoxClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to have my class be composed of several elements of other classes and update given an event trigger and render differently based on that
Basically,  onClick it would change the text from "NO" to "YES"
How would I go about doing that?